How to get call details Error and Warnings from API
I've been trying to retrieve the error and message fields from the "Errors and Warnings" associated with my twilio call using the python SDK (or any http request). I can't find anywhere in the documentation that references this.
It doesn't seem to be on the CallInstance returned by client.calls.get(call_sid).fetch()
Is there some way to query for this information using the Call SID that i'm missing?


Do you mean you get the error code but not the message details?

I get the Status "Failed" under "Properties". But I get no information under the "Errors and Warnings" header

The response from the call resource API should have a link showing how to fetch the notifications associated with the call.
With this, you can then make that API call to fetch the notification SID(s) (which look like NOxxxxx),
then finally use that notification SID to fetch the the error information related to that notification SID via the monitor alert API



Do I need to make an HTTP request for the resource JSON -> or is there anyway in the python SDK to get the NOxxxxx simpler?

I'm afraid it's a two-step approach in Python as well

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

From Twilio documentation Troubleshooting Undelivered Messages:

You can find all of the possible errors and their associated causes and solutions at API Errors and Warnings Dictionary page.

As your error in above SS shown is 32017 and it details can be found here:
Description
Intermediary / Carrier Analytics blocked call due to poor reputation score on the telephone number
Possible Causes

The calling number has a low answer rate from end users
The calling number generates low duration calls
The calling number is responsible for large volumes of unwanted calls

Possible Solutions
Register the telephone numbers with the analytic providers. To reach the major mobile carrier's analytic providers, please register the telephone numbers at www.freecallerregistry.com. To reach T-Mobile's analytic provider directly to register numbers, please go to https://portal.firstorion.com
to register numbers. Going direct to the analytic provider has a faster turnaround of being registered / call being delivered to end user
